# Insurance Liability for a recently registered Ontario corporation

Tags: canada, insurance, corporation, liability

I just registered a corporation in Ontario, and I'm about to get a contract from USA as a Programmer. I applied for a general liability insurance online in many sites, but they keep rejecting it because the corporation's income is expected to be 100% from USA. Some of them said that the maximum they can tolerate is 20% from USA and the rest must come from Canada !!
I'm new to this, I never heard about these restrictions. I'm sure there are many Canadian corporations doing business only in USA, I'm wondering where do they get their liability insurance.
Please help if you can, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you need liability insurance? Many people in your situation would skip it.

Comment: Have you checked with any US-based insurers?  You might also want to consult an attorney about how liability works in this case.  You may find that you are personally liable despite the corporation.

Comment: gaefan, the consulting agency I'm subcontracting from asked for it. I would skip it if I have a choice as the risk is really zero given the type of work I'm doing. This is really free money for the insurer to grab.

Comment: jwh20, I haven't yet. But some people I know say that it's more likely the corporation should be insured in Canada. But, I'm not really sure.

Comment: jwh20, I just tried to request a quote from couple USA insurance companies, you can only select US states and US ZIP code.